# What is "curl: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 73" telling me?

Tags: shell-script, curl

What does this cURL error mean and where can I find more related information?

```
curl: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 73
```

I'm writing a shell script to query the Splunk API.  In some cases, after 5 minutes, I get this error.  Sometimes I can rerun the script and the error goes away and I get my desired output.

Here is what I see on my terminal.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed          Time             Curr.
                                 Dload  Upload Total    Current  Left    Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:01 --:--:--     0
curl: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 73
```

A sample search is this.  I'll substitute "spock" for a hosthame.  This search does succeed on other hosts, so this specific search isn't somehow incorrect and causing the problem.

```
search index=os_nix host=spock source=/var/adm/messages latest=-30d NOT snmpd authentication (error OR fail OR failure) | head
```

I am building my command like this.

```
URLPROTO='https://'
URLHOST='splunkapi.example.com'
URLPORT=':8089'
URLDIR='/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export'
URL="${URLPROTO}${URLHOST}${URLPORT}${URLDIR}"
luser=(read from user input)
lpassword=(read from user input)
OUTFILE=(generated from hostname and the type of search I'm running) 
mySEARCH=(read from input file)
USER=(User ID read from environment)
```

The actually command is this.

```
curl -k -o "${OUTFILE}" -u ${luser:=${USER}}:${lpasswd} ${URL} -d search="${mySEARCH}" -d output_mode="csv"
```

My script loops through a list of hosts, read from an external file, performing several searches, read from a different external file, against each host.  To clarify further, I can run my script and I get two or three failures out of a total of thirty total searches.  The entire run doesn't fail, just two or three individual host/search pairs.  The failure isn't limited to a specific host/search pair or a specific host or a specific search, as I can rerun my script and the failures stand a good chance of succeeding.

What is the cURL error trying to tell me?

If it matters, this is AIX.

```
curl 7.11.1 (powerpc-ibm-aix5.2.0.0) libcurl/7.11.1 OpenSSL/0.9.7g ipv6
Protocols: ftp gopher telnet dict ldap http file https ftps
Features: IPv6 SSL NTLM Largefile
```

Comment: Maybe the host has a "bad certificate" like self-signed for example. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875674/my-password-curl-is-failing-sometimes)

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis Would a bad certificate return immediately or wait for a timeout?  Your link makes me think a different authorization method is needed, such as "echo -ne "username:password" | base64 --wrap 0" in my shell script, or "uuencode -m" in AIX-land?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl reports these errors because Splunk doesn't return any data.  (My search returned data for most hosts but a time-specific window would cause it to occasionally fail.)

Splunk times out after 5 minutes and disconnects curl, errno 73.  The curl exit code (56)  is "Failure in receiving network data."  Splunk doesn't send anything, so no data to receive.

Thank you both @thrig and @OscarAkaElvis for assisting.

Answer (score 2):

The names associated with the `errno` "error numbers" should be in the file `errno.h` usually stashed somewhere under `/usr/include`, though a webby search turns up:

http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmp.html

Which for 73 and AIX is "Connection reset by peer". So for some reason the peer (or something between the client and the peer) reset the connection.

Comment: Wow.  Nice on-line error-code table.

Comment: How would I interpret this error code?
curl: (56) SSL read: errno -5961

Comment: @IAmJeff too little context to tell, the return code can be negative as it's an `int`, so could either be a negative read, or something did set that (`grep` out of AIX and OpenSSL sources, maybe), or something else went awry.